# Any way to get a statistics on aborted posts?

Tags: feature-request

One of the great things I like about stack overflow and the rest of the sites is more often than not the act of fully writing out the question makes me discover the answer.  I would love to get some sort of statistic on how many posts I started, typed more than a paragraph, and then closed without submitting.

Comment: SO doesn't know what posts you didn't submit by defnition

Comment: But it could, the page catches the close event already.  It could run a bit of JS that sees how long the page has been open and how much text has been added and fire off a query to tally that info.

Comment: Not a serious request, but would give interesting insight into effectiveness of SO as getting the user to view the whole problem.

Comment: It's something along the lines of an abandonment metric; someone starts asking a question, but doesn't actually submit the question.  That's not terribly difficult to *do*, but insofar as mere mortals knowing those statistics, I don't see any value to it.

Comment: In particular, I would be bothered if other users could view such statistics about me. And if it were just viewing my own, it wouldn't really give me much "interesting insight" in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leaving out the issue of whether this data could be reliably collected, I'm not sure there'd be any meaningful way to glean any useful information from that data. There could be all sorts of reason for abandoning a question, and those reasons are all over the place;

- My dog walked in and begged to go outside (Crap! I said the word... pardon me for a few minutes... K; back!)
- Typing the question made me realize what the answer was.
- Typing the question made me realize I really had no clue what the problem was, to ask a decent question.
- The more I typed, the more angry I became at not being able to figure it out, so I slammed my keyboard, breaking it.
- The side bar presented a good duplicate while I typed.
- Some person in a chatroom/my office/the Help Desk I'd been on hold with came through with an answer.
- I got tired of trying to figure out how to format my post.
- When bouncing back to my IDE to get code to paste, I hit "Build" and suddenly, it worked.

Here's what I'm getting at: We have no way to know which of the above reasons might apply, and those reasons are all over the place. Some are absolutely meaningless, some might suggest things we could improve on the site, and others suggest things are working *very well*.

Comment: "The side bar presented a good duplicate while I typed." I do wonder if clicks on the sidebar are saved somewhere.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That was one item I thought of that could have some possible useful information. Of course, it's possible the question is still abandoned for another reason, but I think this is much more deterministic than anything else here. And I'd definitely be curious about that.